# How come I can't flatMap from Option to List in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

When I try

`Some(1).flatMap(_ => List(2))`

I get

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: Option[?]
```

But doing `Some(1).map(_ => List(2)).flatten` works.  How come I get a compile error in the first case?

Comment: Another short fix is to use `Some(1).flatMap(_ => Some(2)).toList`, as `Option.flatMap` must return an `Option`

Comment: I'd expect `List(2,3)` just like if I did `map().flatten`

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure the list has a zero or one elements you can do this:

```
option.flatMap(_ => list.headOption)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this, because the type system forbids this. The type of Option.flatMap is

```
     final def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ Option[B]): Option[B]
```

So your function must return an Option type, not a List type.

If you want to convert to a different type, you have to use .map(...).flatten

Answer (score 3):

Not to say it doesn't work on other Scala versions, but it doesn't work for me:

```
scala> Some(1).map(_ => List(2)).flatten
<console>:8: error: Cannot prove that List[Int] <:< Option[B].
              Some(1).map(_ => List(2)).flatten
                                        ^
```

More importantly, what would be the result of `Some("abc").flatMap(s => s.toList)`, or its equivalent `Some(List('a','b','c')).flatten`?

Comment: I get `Iterable[Int] = List(2)` using scala 2.9.2